# Unable to connect to mongodb running in virtualbox (host: Mac OS, guest: CentOS)

Tags: networking, macos, virtual-machine, centos, mongodb

I am using CentOS 7 in a virtualmachine running on Mac OS X using Virtualbox.

Unfortunately I am not able to connect to the VM's database from my Mac OS host. I am using `NAT` as network for the VM and defined a rule to forward host port 3017 to VM's port 27017 which is mongod's default port. As can be seen using `VBoxManage showvminfo CentOS | grep 'NIC`:

```
[hostOS]$ VBoxManage showvminfo CentOS | grep 'NIC'
NIC 1:           MAC: 080027EF3CC0, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = http, protocol = tcp, host ip = , host port = 3080, guest ip = , guest port = 80
NIC 1 Rule(1):   name = mongo, protocol = tcp, host ip = , host port = 3017, guest ip = , guest port = 27017
NIC 1 Rule(2):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = , host port = 3022, guest ip = , guest port = 22
```

I am using CentOS' firewall on the guest system, but added MongoDB's default port `27017` to the `public` zone definition as seen here:

```
[guestOS]$ firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp0s3
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 27017/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

In addtion `SELINUX` is disabled:

```
[guestOS]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

So I wanted to check, whether port-forwarding from my host to the guest VM is working as desired. Using `nc -w 3 -v localhost 3017` shows up, that port-forwarding should work as desired:

```
[hostOS]$ nc -w 3 -v localhost 3017
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif lo0
    src 127.0.0.1 port 50595
    dst 127.0.0.1 port 3017
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to localhost port 3017 [tcp/event_listener] succeeded!
```

The next step was to make sure, that `mongod` is really running on the VM's OS. So I checked `mongod`'s status:

```
[guestOS]$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: active (running) since So 2016-02-21 20:35:31 CET; 4min 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1167 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1236 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─1236 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf

Feb 21 20:35:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
Feb 21 20:35:28 localhost.localdomain runuser[1191]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Feb 21 20:35:31 localhost.localdomain runuser[1191]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Feb 21 20:35:31 localhost.localdomain mongod[1167]: Starting mongod: [  OK  ]
Feb 21 20:35:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
```

In addition to that I am able to connect to the database inside the VM like:

```
[guestOS]$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-02-21T20:35:31.414+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-02-21T20:35:31.415+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-02-21T20:35:31.415+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 4096 processes, 64000 files. Number of processes should be at least 32000 : 0.5 times number of files.
2016-02-21T20:35:31.415+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

However, I am not able to connect to the database from the host OS:

```
[hostOS]$ mongo --port 3017
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3017/test
2016-02-21T20:47:38.810+0100 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2016-02-21T20:47:38.813+0100 E QUERY    Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:3017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 }
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

So let me summarize the whole thing a bit:

- using CentOS 7 as guest in virtualbox on Mac OS
- using `NAT` as network interface
- forwarding host port `3017` to guest port `27017` is working
- ensured `mongod` is running on guest OS
- disabled `SELINUX` in CentOS
- added port `27017` to CentOS' firewall exceptions
- connecting to monogdb from host OS raises `Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:3017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 }`

How can I get that error solved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching along the web for the raised error message I thought that this was a SSL/TLS related problem since the default version of the Mac OS mongo shell does not support SSL/TLS connections (however, the homebrew version does).

So I tried to establish a encrypted connection which failed and does not solve the problem.

After that I thought about having external access to the database. Virtualbox does port-forwarding to the VM, so incoming requests are done from the network interface of the VM. Due to that I added the IP address of the VM to the allowed IPs in mongo's config `/etc/mongod.conf` as described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/):

```
# Listen to local and LAN interface.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15
```

Finally, this solved my connection issues.

Comment: Just wanted to +1 the answer and say thanks as I've been struggling with this for a bit now and this simple change solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (Windows 10 host, Ubuntu 18.04 guest). In my case the host IP changes frequently, so adding its IP to bind_ip didn't help. I edited /etc/mongodb.conf to replace

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

with

```
bind_ip_all = true
```

and all was well after I restarted mongodb. Note that this is not a great idea security-wise unless you know exactly what you're doing. In my case all my mongodb data is throwaway test data, and I'm on a trusted network. YMMV.

Comment: this was the way to go for me on Windows 10 and mongodb 4.2 but it should be `bindIpAll: true` in my case